# Computing modular inverse in extension fields

Tags: extension-field, elliptic-curves

I am currently studying elliptic curves and Weil pairings. Curves are defined on $\mathbb{F}_{p}$, and to establish the Weil pairing extension field $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ is used (with a polynom for reduction).

I have created some basic programs to play with small finite fields, but now I am stuck with modular inverse in $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ (in $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ I was simply doing $x^{p-2}$ to compute the inverse of $x$). Can someone please point me to an algorithm to use in extension fields ?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: If $a \in \mathbb{F}_{p^n}, a \ne 0$ then $a^{p^n-1} = 1$ and $a^{-1} = a^{p^n-2}$

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly, I am now able to add and multiply points on $E(\mathbb{F_{p^2}})$ !

Comment: Great, did you construct $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ as  $\mathbb{F}_{p}[\sqrt{c}] = \{a+b \sqrt{c}, (a,b) \in (\mathbb{F}_{p})^2\}$ where $c$ is a quadratic non residue in $\mathbb{F}_p$ ?

Comment: I used $\mathbb{F}_{p}[\beta] = \{ a + \beta b\}$ with $\beta^2 + \beta + 1 = 0$.

So to multiply two numbers $\{ a + \beta b\}$ and $\{ c + \beta d\}$ I compute $(ac - bd) + \beta (ad + bc - bd)$

Comment: So $\beta$ is a 3rd-root of unity, and it works only if $3 \nmid p-1$, otherwise $\{ \alpha+\beta b, (a,b) \in \mathbb{F}_p \}$ is not an integral domain. What I wrote with $\sqrt{c}$ works for every $p \ne 2$.

Comment: I was doing my tests in $\mathbb{F}_{11}$, as there is no $\beta$ such as $\beta^3 = 1$. If I want to choose a $c$ for $\mathbb{F}_{11}$, I can use $c = 2$ (for example), but not $c = 3$ because $5^2 = 3$ and so $c = 3$ is not a quadratic non residue in $\mathbb{F}_{11}$. Do I understand correctly ?

Comment: No. What you need to know is if $x^2+ Ax+B$ is irreducible as a polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$. In that case $\mathbb{F}_p[x]/(x^2+ Ax+B)$ (which is the same as $\{a+b \beta, (a,b) \in (\mathbb{F}_{p})^2\}, \beta^2 = -A\beta -B$) is an integral domain with $p^2$ elements, and hence a field with $p^2$ elements.

Comment: So if I use the same examples as above (with the $c$ values), it would mean I could choose $x^2 - 2 = 0$ as polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_{11}$ because it is irreducible, but this would not work with $x^2 - 3 = 0$, as this polynomial can be factorized as $x^2 - 3 = (x - 5)(x - 6)$ ?

To check if the polynomial is irreducible I guess the idea is to use one of the algorithm described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials_over_finite_fields ?